# Change the way REST resources are registered in Netbeans

Tags: web-services, netbeans, netbeans-7

When I wanted to generate a RESTful Webservice with Netbeans I was asked for "the way REST resources will be registered in the application". I accidentally clicked on "Netbeans will generate a subclass of javax.ws.rs.core.Application [...]" instead of "Create default Jersey REST servlet adaptor [...]" (see image below).

[image: http://netbeans.org/images_www/articles/70/websvc/rest/ee6-rest-configuration.png]

Source: [Getting Started with RESTful Web Services](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html)

I deleted the generated subclass and created the Jersey REST servlet adaptor manually. Everything works fine, except that Netbeans is still generating a subclass of Application on every publish. Do you know a way how to switch this off? (I do not get the dialog a second time.)

Comment: Thanks for asking this questions (and for the answers below), it helped me solve a tricky problem, with rest.config.type=ide it was generated an unwanted additional  @javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("resources") public class ApplicationConfig, and the /resources path was blocking my JSF web app style files like /resources/css/style.css, very tricky, changing it to rest.config.type=user worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to remove the file

```
MyProject/MyProject-war/nbproject/rest-build.xml
```

Then I got some import/dependency errors when compiling. After solving these (removed the import from another xml and a dependency to `generate-rest-config` from build-impl.xml) it wasn't generating a subclass of Application anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the Files tab and look in nbproject, then open project.properties

scroll down until you see these lines:

```
rest.config.type=ide
rest.resources.path=resources
rest.support.on=true
```

The default resources path I think is webresources, so you can change that, but to answer the question I think you want to adjust rest.support.on to either true or false. The other option (middle option in dialog box) I think is rest.config.type which can be set =user.

Answer (score 1):

you can remove the below lines from: nbproject/project.properties

```
rest.config.type=ide
rest.resources.path=resources
rest.support.on=true
```

then after you save a rest related file netbeans will show you the message box again.

Comment: you can only delete:
`rest.resources.path=resources
rest.support.on=true`

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Netbeans 7.2 and I can access that dialog in the GUI. Go to the Projects window and under your project there should be a "RESTful Web Services" package. Right clicking on that gives you this menu:

[image]

This allows you to change your configuration.

NOTE: I have some coworkers that are running Netbeans 7.3.1 and they don't see that option in that menu.